Output disparity on Chkdsk and Drive Properties
I recently noticed that one of my drives is having issues and I suspect it may be failing. Apps on this drive are slow to load (sometimes wont load at all and freeze), and any game that is on this drive starts to freeze after some time which is unusual as I have had no issues at all until today. To investigate the health of the drive I right-clicked the drive in Windows Explorer, then 'Properties' and then ran the 'Error Checking' service and got this message:

Just to make sure I ran a scan anyways, and after it was complete I got the following message:

This led me to check the log files in Event Viewer to see more about what could be going on. While I am not an advanced user to fully comprehend all of the log messages, I did notice the following lines:
Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

So you can see there seems to be a disparity here in what Windows is telling me. One one hand its saying 'There was a problem repairing this drive' and on the other hand its saying 'there are no problems'.
Can anyone explain what this apparent disparity is about? Here is a link to the Event Viewer log file.
Lastly, and perhaps unrelated, I checked the Security permissions on this drive, and noticed that somehow I didn't have full permissions (no 'Modify' and no 'Full Control' which I should have). When I tried to apply full control to this drive I got the following error output:

So it would seem there is an I/O device input error (which is never good).
Is this something that could be related to the possibly failure of this device?
EDIT - It seems the problem is intermittent. Apps and files are ok on the drive for about 30 minutes, then a big freeze happens; Windows Explorer freezes up when navigating to the drive, Disk Management wont work, and I can't open files on the drive with any app that is associated with the filetype. Seems that this I/O issue is causing read errors. Not sure what to do considering Windows is telling me the drive is 'OK'
Another strange thing is that SOMETIMES (not always), if I log out of Windows, and then log back in again, the problem is gone (at least for a while).

Run a smart test and [edit] to include the output.

@DavidPostill thanks. I ran this and all it said was OK OK OK OK OK  (I guess one instance for each drive)?

An intermittent problem usually means a failing drive. What are the SMART attributes of disk H? If you don't have a utility for this then use CrystalDiskInfo.
